# Why I get the message Two-way binding requires Path or XPath.?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, two-way-binding

I am creating a `TextBox` and a `TextBlock` at runtime and bind that to the database fields at runtime. The code is below:

```
LstConfigFields = dbContext.ConfigFields.Where(c => c.ConfigId == this.Uid).ToList();
foreach (ConfigField rec in LstConfigFields)
{
    TextBlock TBlock = new TextBlock();
    TBlock.Text = rec.TextBlockText;

    TextBox TBox = new TextBox();                
    TBox.SetBinding(TextBox.TextProperty,new Binding(rec.DatabaseField));

    if ((bool)rec.IsVisible)
    {
        stackPanel1.Children.Add(TBlock);
        stackPanel1.Children.Add(TBox);
    }
}
```

But I am getting this message :

> Two-way binding requires Path or XPath.

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If DatabaseField is read-only you should use [OneWay Binding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.mode%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Comment: Okay, try to add Mode=TwoWay to binding.

Comment: But this will be a dynamic control added to the stackpanel at runtime, how can I add through code?

Comment: new Binding("MyProperty") { Source = myPropertyHolder, Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay }

Comment: Source = myPropertyHolder , what shall I specify in the myPropertyHolder ? Thanks in advance

Comment: You want to bind to property of some object. Is't "myPropertyHolder". Usually it is ViewModel. For example you have object currentUser (class User) with property Name. So, binding for current user will be: new Binding("Name") { Source = currentUser, Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay }

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15890/discussion-between-sony-and-rover)

Comment: You can edit the answer and add the information you have discussed in comments

Answer (score 1):

If the `Text` property of the bound object contains symbols specific to `XPath` syntax, dynamic binding will try to interpret them, thus failing you the whole process by creating wrong binding